# Maximum Likelihood Estimation - Symbol Change

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to understand why when simplifying the exponential likelihood function, the symbol changed from a product of sequences to summation and why isn't the theta in the exponential to the power of n?.

$$
\ p(y | \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\theta \cdot exp(-\theta \cdot y_{i})
$$

$$
\ p(y | \theta) =  \theta ^ {n} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n} exp(-\theta \cdot y_{i})
$$

$$
\ p(y | \theta) =  \theta ^ {n} \cdot exp(-\theta \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i})
$$

Comment: Take $n=2$ and see what you get by multiplying $\theta e^{-\theta y_1}$ and $\theta e^{-\theta y_2}$. Then take $n=3$ and generalise.

Comment: Ah thank you, now I understand, because of index laws!